# Как составить запрос в SQL для триггера, чтобы поле из одной таблицы считалось через COUNT поля другой таблицы

Tags: sql, sqlite3

У меня есть две таблицы: events (важные столбцы: id, members_on_event) и watched_events (важные столбцы: id_event, on_event). Мне нужно написать запрос для триггера: members_on_event равно количеству записей в watched_events, у которых id = id_event и on_event = 'Y'.
В SQLiteStudio написал следующий триггер, который действует AFTER UPDATE OF on_event:

```
UPDATE events
SET members_on_event = (SELECT COUNT(on_event) 
FROM watched_events inner join events on id_event = id
GROUP BY id_event);
```

Проблема в том, что он работает только для id_event = 1 и изменяет members_on_event для всех записей в events.

Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: Ваш update не имеет ограничений where, ровно как селект, считающий count.

Comment: А вот как написать для них ограничения?

Comment: Добавить WHERE к update и select -> `udpate events set members_on_event = () WHERE id=ZXC`

Comment: Я дописал WHERE id = (SELECT id_event FROM watched_events) для UPDATE, теперь он считает members_on_event только для первой записи

Comment: Приложите код DDL создания таблиц (create table) и наполнения их данными (insert), тогда быстро получите ответ.

Comment: `WHERE id = new.id_event` - это добавить к коду триггера.

Comment: WHERE id = new.id_event действительно сработало, спасибо огромное за помощь!